# Como usar regex começando no meio da string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Eu tenho uma string bastante grande e gostaria de verificar se um trecho dela casa com uma regex. O problema é que esse trecho está no meio da string, em uma posição bem específica. Como terei de fazer isso várias vezes (strings diferentes, regexes diferentes e posições diferentes) gostaria que essa verificação fosse feita de forma eficiente, sem ter que:

1. Fazer uma substring, o que criaria novas strings desnecessariamente:

   ```
   var sub = str.substring(pos); // Cria um novo objeto, potencialmente bem grande
   regex.exec(sub);
   ```

   ou:
2. Fazer a busca globalmente, o que não só percorre partes da string que não me interessam (i.e. aquelas antes da posição desejada) como também pode não me dar o resultado que eu quero em absoluto (ex.: se há interseção entre um casamento anterior e a parte da string que me interessa):

   ```
   var resultado = regex.exec(str); // Assumindo que regex possui a flag g
   while ( resultado && resultado.index < pos )
       resultado = regex.exec(str);
   if ( resultado.index == pos )
       ...
   ```

É possível fazer isso? Os métodos usuais de casamento (`String.match`, `RegExp.test` e `RegExp.exec`) não possuem parâmetros para especificar a posição da string de onde iniciar a execução, e mesmo o `String.search` não possui essa opção. Há alguma outra maneira?

Comment: Relacionado (acho que não chega a ser dup): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/442142/112052

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito através da *flag* [`sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky) e da propriedade [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) (a mesma usada pela *flag* `global`). Basta criar a regex com essa *flag* e em seguida atribuir a posição que se deseja buscar:

```js
var re = /\w+/y;
var str = "....abc....def...";

re.lastIndex = 4;
console.log(re.exec(str)); // ["abc"]

re.lastIndex = 11;
console.log(re.exec(str)); // ["def"]

re.lastIndex = 2;
console.log(re.exec(str)); // null

re.lastIndex = 5; // Funciona em qualquer índice
console.log(re.exec(str)); // ["bc"]
```

(Nota: essa *flag* somente foi padronizada recentemente pelo ES2015, de modo que [só é suportada pelos browsers em suas versões mais recentes](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_y_and_u_flags), e o suporte nas plataformas móveis ainda é limitado)

Essa flag é necessária porque: a) se a regex não for global, o valor da propriedade `lastIndex` é ignorado; b) se a regex for global, ele busca a partir do `lastIndex`, em vez de começar o casamento exatamente no `lastIndex` (e não adianta usar `^` no início da regex, pois como não se está no início da string, a execução falhará):

```js
var str = "....abc....def....";

var re1 = /\w+/;
re1.lastIndex = 11; // Deveria pegar a segunda palavra
console.log(re1.exec(str)); // ["abc"]

var re2 = /\w+/g;
re2.lastIndex = 2; // Deveria falhar
console.log(re2.exec(str)); // ["abc"]

var re3 = /^\w+/g;
re3.lastIndex = 11; // Deveria pegar a segunda palavra
console.log(re3.exec(str)); // null
```

Comment: Vale ressaltar que a flag `/y` [não é suportado por todos os navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Compatibilidade_de_navegador)

Comment: @Mariano De fato. Essa flag já é usada no Firefox há anos, mas só foi padronizada pelo ES6. Atualmente [todos os browsers modernos para desktop dão suporte](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_y_and_u_flags) - incluindo o Edge, mas excluindo o IE em todas as suas versões. Nas plataformas móveis, só o iOS 10 por enquanto... Vou atualizar a resposta com essa informação.