# O que é a flag "y" em expressões regulares? Qual a sua função?

Tags: javascript, regex

Há algum tempo descobri que expressões regulares também podem usar a *flag* `y`, chamada de *sticky*.

Não entendi muito bem a sua função. Qual o seu propósito? Há alguma relação com outra *flag*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ela é usada para indicar que a busca deve começar a partir da posição indicada por [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex), e só dá *match* se for encontrado exatamente naquela posição (diferente de uma regex *non-sticky*, que verifica em qualquer posição da string):

```js
// expressões para buscar uma letra minúscula
let notSticky = /[a-z]/;
let sticky = /[a-z]/y;

let s = '123abc';
console.log(notSticky.test(s)); // true

console.log(sticky.test(s)); // false
sticky.lastIndex = 3;
console.log(sticky.test(s)); // true

sticky.lastIndex = 1;
console.log(sticky.test(s)); // false
```

A primeira tentativa com a regex *sticky* falha porque `lastIndex` começa com o valor zero.

Você pode verificar se a regex tem essa *flag* usando a [propriedade `sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky):

```js
let notSticky = /[a-z]/;
let sticky = /[a-z]/y;

console.log(notSticky.sticky); // false
console.log(sticky.sticky); // true
```

**Mas atenção**, se a regex usar o [marcador](http://regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` (início da string), a *flag* `y` pode dar problema:

```js
// verifica se a string começa com uma letra minúscula
let r = /^[a-z]/y;

let s = '12abc';
console.log(r.test(s)); // false

r.lastIndex = 2;
console.log(r.test(s)); // false, a posição 2 não é o início da string

r.lastIndex = 2;
console.log(r.test('abc')); // false, a posição 2 não é o início da string

r.lastIndex = 0;
console.log(r.test('abc')); // true, a posição 0 é o início da string
```

---

## Relação com outras *flags*

Se for a *flag case insensitive* (`i`), não há interferência:

```js
// com a flag "i", para procurar maiúsculas e minúsculas
let r = /[a-z]/yi;

let s = '123ABC';

console.log(r.test(s)); // false
r.lastIndex = 3;
console.log(r.test(s)); // true
```

Com as *flags* `s` e `u` também não há problema (a primeira muda o comportamento do ponto, que passa a considerar também quebras de linha, e a segunda habilita o modo Unicode - nada que interfira no funcionamento *sticky* em si).

Se você usar a *flag* `m` (que faz com que os [marcadores](http://regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` passem a significar também o início e fim de uma linha):

```js
// verifica tem uma letra minúscula no início da string ou início de linha
let r = /^[a-z]/ym;

let s = '12abc';
console.log(r.test(s)); // false

r.lastIndex = 2;
console.log(r.test(s)); // false, a posição 2 não é o início da string

r.lastIndex = 2;
console.log(r.test('abc')); // false, a posição 2 não é o início da string

r.lastIndex = 0;
console.log(r.test('abc')); // true, a posição 0 é o início da string

r.lastIndex = 2;
console.log(r.test('1\nabc')); // true, a posição 2 é o início de linha
```

Já o uso com a *flag* `g` pode causar alguma confusão (testes abaixo feitos no Chrome):

```js
let s = 'ab12cd34xy56';

let r = /[a-z]/yg;
r.lastIndex = 4;
console.log(s.match(r)); // ["a", "b"]

r = /[a-z]/y;
r.lastIndex = 4;
console.log(s.match(r)); // ["c"]

r = /[a-z]/g;
r.lastIndex = 4;
console.log(s.match(r)); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "x", "y"]
```

Com ambas as *flags*, o `lastIndex` foi ignorado e a busca começou no início da string. Mas ele não encontrou todas as ocorrências, somente as duas primeiras (a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky#Description) diz que neste caso a *flag* `g` é ignorada, mas o resultado é estranho, porque se fosse realmente isso, deveria ser o mesmo do segundo teste, ou seja, `['c']`).

Usando somente `y`, é o comportamento normal que já vimos acima, busca apenas uma ocorrência no índice indicado.

E usando somente `g`, ele encontra todas as ocorrências, sempre começando do início da string, independente do que estava setado em `lastIndex` antes.

Minha conclusão é que deve-se evitar usar as *flags* `y` e `g` juntas. E faz sentido, pois uma só faz a busca a partir de uma posição exata, e outra busca todas as ocorrências da string (ou seja, são objetivos contraditórios que não têm como coexistir).